# How can I open a file via autohotkey at certain time of the day?

Tags: timer, autohotkey

I could not find a way for a simple script at autohotkey that can open a file at a specific time of the day. Any help?

```
hour = 09 
min = 00
difhr := hour - A_hour difmin := min - A_min
if difhr > 0  
sleepH := difhr * 3600000
 else
```

Comment: If you're asking us to find / write a script for you; it's offtopic. Otherwise show us your code.

Comment: i found it is not good to use SetTimer and the suggestion is

Comment: where should I add the line to open the file?

Comment: This code doesn't even look like it runs. Is there an error message? Or what is the specific question?

Comment: I think the question is in the title

Comment: My question is very simple: how can set up autohotkey to run a script at a specific time. Yes, that code is incomplete and for that reason I asked here. Thanks

Comment: Sounds like [Windows Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx) to me. Unless there's a specific reason for using AHK, why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 good ways to do this that I can think of.

SetTimer:

```
#Persistent

SetTimer, CheckTime, 5000
Return

CheckTime:
TheTime = %A_Hour%%A_Min%
If (TheTime = 1525) && !(Ran)
{
    Run, C:\Test.txt
    Ran := 1
}
```

Loop:

```
Loop
{
    CurrTime = %A_Hour%%A_Min%
    If (CurrTime = 1520) && !(Ran)
    {
        msgbox, Run File
        Ran := 1
    }
    Sleep 5000
}
```

Comment: Nice of you to answer, Elliot!

Comment: I chose the first one and it worked. I understand that this script is not slowing my whole system or should I be concerned about it?

Comment: if my computer is off at the time of that script how would it be the line to open the file ASAP?

Comment: @AMDG - that is *different* question - but you might have to ask it on SuperUser. In Stack Exchange we have to stay on topic, you know.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `return` for the `CheckTime`?

Comment: @bgmCoder, Best practices say yes, but if you are not going to have any code following the script provided, it can be omitted without issue.

Comment: Note, that you can use a much more efficient version (without checking every few seconds) using [this method by Lexikos](//autohotkey.com/board/topic/19960-got-problems-while-checking-the-system-time/?p=131436).